# Unexpected character in the filename I'm writing to

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, shellcode

My problem is related with **Assembler and Shellcoding**.

I started off by writing my first shellcode and it worked out pretty well so far. I then made an assembly script of the following *C* code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("test.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, "Hello World!", 6);

    return 0;
}
```

### The assembly code for that piece looks like this:

```
global _start

_start:

    xor eax, eax ; null eax reg

    push   0x7478742e       ; push "test.txt" on stack
    push   0x74736574

    mov ebx, esp            ; first Argument
    mov cl, 0x41            ; Flags O_CREAT | O_WRONLY
    mov al, 0x5             ; sys_open
    int 0x80

    push 0x736b6330         ; "shellcodingr0cks"
    push 0x72676e69
    push 0x646f636c
    push 0x6c656853

    mov ebx, eax            ; file identifier
    mov ecx, esp            ; string on the stack
    mov dl, 0x10            ; 0x10 is the size of the string
    mov al, 0x4             ;  sys_write
    int 0x80

    xor eax, eax            ; exit proc
    inc eax
    int 0x80
```

The Program works pretty well and I've got the expected output but there is one problem and I don't know why this is occurring.

The filename of the file I'm writing to should be `test.txt` but it is writing to `test.txt^A`. I don't know where the `^A` is coming from, nor do I know how to fix it.

Does anyone know what is wrong, and how I can fix it?

Comment: ^A is generally ascii null, e.g. char(0)

Comment: You need to zero terminate it.

Comment: Thats what i thought too, but i cant zero Terminate because in shellcoding its not possible to have a \x00 Byte in the shellcode, any other possibility s?

Comment: @MarcB no, it's `char(1)`. `^@` is `char(0)` and you won't see that for obvious reasons.

Comment: ah, yeah. close 'nuff

Comment: @user6431813 since you already have a zero in `eax` just use that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast Answers :) gonna try this and will come back later

Comment: You are fundamentally mistaken in believing that you cannot push a 0-valued word onto the stack in the same manner that you have pushed the effectively arbitrary constants defining the printable part of your data.

Comment: @ChrisStratton no, he is not mistaken. Shellcode can not contain zero bytes, so he can't just do `push 0` because that would contain a zero byte (the immediate in the instruction). He can however do `push eax` because the machine code for that has no zero byte and `eax` is already zero.

Comment: I tried it with the eax register and it worked fine:) Thank you. Havent thought of that.. :D and yes i was just thinking of pushing a null-byte directly with push 0x00 and that would not work in a shellcode if i remember that correctly, but with xored register this works fine.

Comment: `mov al, 0x4` doesn't zero the rest of `eax`.  This will get the wrong system call if `open(2)` returns a file descriptor above 0xFF, which will happen if this code runs in a process that already has a file descriptors 0-255 in use.  You probably need another `xor eax,eax` before the mov, or `movzx eax,al` after. Another option is `cbw` + `cwde` (since the sign bit of al is 0), but that's also 3 bytes.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, you are right:) gonna edit this.

Comment: @Jester if you want to you can post your Answer so that the Question is closed:)